# How do I add a property changed callback to the Name property on object?

Tags: wpf, callback, dependency-properties

Since I didn't register the property how would I add a property changed callback?

This works:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
    FrameworkElement.NameProperty.AddOwner(typeof(Node), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Node", new PropertyChangedCallback(NamePropertyChanged)));`
```

but there is a warning which I don't understand, so maybe there is another way of doing this:

> WpfApplication1.Node.NameProperty' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NameProperty'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class Node seems to be derived from FrameworkElement (or a subclass of FrameworkElement). Both Node and FrameworkElement define

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty;
```

which generates the compiler warning. Just write

```
public static new readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty ...
```

in class Node.

You could also write

```
FrameworkElement.NameProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(Node),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Node", new PropertyChangedCallback(NamePropertyChanged)));
```

in Node's static constructor.